# moment.js Invalid date when formatting a date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to format the date that is coming from a server, but I am getting an error that date is not valid.

```
moment("2016-11-31T18:00:00.000+02:00").format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // Invalid date
```

EDIT: I've checked and if the day is 30 not 31 it works, jsfiddle updated

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/7093/)

Comment: I think this bit is causing the problem perhaps "+02:00"

Comment: Very unlikely, please check I've updated the jsfiddle

Comment: Apologies didn't see the fiddle!

Comment: The problem is the T; I'm not sure why though--in theory it supports ISO-8601.

Comment: The day being past the end of November may also be an issue, although with the T removed, and UTC added, it properly changes the day to Dec. (`"2016-11-31 18:00:00.000+02:00UTC"`)

Comment: Yes that is right Dave, I've updated the question, can anyone explain one this happens?

Comment: The time is causing it to go into the next day no?

Comment: Yes possibly. But the time is 18:00:00.000+02:00 so why it should be going to the next day?

Comment: What version of moment are you using?  http://momentjs.com/  The latest according to the site is 2.17.0 but the fiddle shows 2.5.1

Comment: I have "moment": "^2.13.0" in my package.json and the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: what about with 2.17.0?

Comment: I have 2.17.0 installed as "^2.13.0" means it is non fixed dependency (because of this: ^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only 30 days in November...